# Launch main method from object with type "Class<?>"

Tags: java, reflection, program-entry-point

I have a object like this

```
Class<?> myClass = getMyClass();
// don't ask about getMyClass() method, it's not important,
just be sure that this method returns a class.
```

Secondly, I'm sure that "myClass" contains "main(String args[])" method.

How can I launch this main method. I guess I should use java.lang.reflect, but I don't know how.

All I want, it's do something like this.

```
String params[] = {"arg1", "arg2"};
cl.main(params);
```

Comment: Where is the question? I can only see deal :)

Comment: @Ashish I found the question fairly clear: how to use reflection to invoke the main method on a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Java tutorial on the reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html):

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class InvokeMain {
    public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
        Class[] argTypes = new Class[] { String[].class };
        Method main = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", argTypes);
        String[] mainArgs = Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length);
        System.out.format("invoking %s.main()%n", c.getName());
        main.invoke(null, (Object)mainArgs);

        // production code should handle these exceptions more gracefully
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use reflection.

```
myClass.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(null, (Object)args);
```

Comment: I consider exceptions that prevent code from working to be major, and I used a comment as well.  The downvote has been removed now that you have fixed your answer.  I do not see said error in Pshemo's answer, which is the exact same as yours except for using `getMethod` instead of `getDeclaredMethod`, which is a suitable alternative under the assumption that the main method is public, as it should be in order to be a valid main method.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, your solution works, indeed, thank you.
I just prefered to vote for Tedd Hopp's answer, becase it comes from Javadoc

Comment: @Vulcan Any small typo is also an exception that prevents code from working, like writing "getMehtod". It is nowhere nearly a case for a downvote, though.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick 

<sub>(I assume that `main` is 1) public (tanks to that `getMethod` will work) and 2) `static`, that is why I pass `null` as first parameter in `invoke`)</sub>

```
myClass.getMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(null, (Object) params);
```

Comment: Why do you cast `params` to `Object`?

Comment: @Vulcan Because `invoke` uses varargs as second argument `invoke(Object obj, Object... args)`. This will make array as one parameter (as expected in `main(String[] args)`, not array of parameters.

Comment: Great catch; this makes your answer the only correct one.  I'm deleting my answer now.

Comment: @Vulcan not the only one, Ted also used it in his answer :)

Comment: Didn't notice that in Ted's answer; he gets an upvote from me as well :)

Comment: `getMethod` works only for public *member* methods. That excludes statics.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Are you sure? Then my Java must have some bug because it works fine for me. I tested it under Eclipse so will try to test it under JRE also.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik `getMethod` does not exclude statics.

Comment: Well, if you tested it, then I have nothing further to add :)

Comment: Indeed, a *member* method is different from an *instance* method.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thx, that indeed could be misleading :)

Answer (score 0):

Obtain a reference to the main method (myClass.getDeclaredMethod) and then call the method (Method.invoke). The details should be obvious if you take a look at the javadocs of the methods.